# Short story about archaeologists on post apocalyptic world finding out about science-fiction

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

I remember reading a short story in an anthology sometime between the end of the 90's and the 2000's. It was the French translation of an English story, thus it could be much older.

I remember the story being about a group of archaeologists excavating ruins and discussing why the galactic empire hasn't contacted them after the apocalypse. What the apocalypse was is not said, only to find out that there is no galactic empire: all the clues they had uncovered came from science-fiction books.

I believe they find out by uncovering an almost intact science-fiction pulp magazine from the 50's or 60's, but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 11):

Sounds a bit like Lester del Rey *To Avenge Man*.

The archaeologists are robots which have been the only "life" on Earth since WW3. A set of sf stories which have survived convince them that mankind was destroyed by hostile extraterrestrials, maybe "Boskone" or "The Eich". They search the Galaxy seeking vengeance on Man's killers, but never find them. The researchers uncover the truth but destroy it so as not to rob robotkind of its "heritage".

Comment: It's available [here](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v23n02_1964-12/page/n155) for free at the internet archive.

Comment: Good one, but that's not it. The archeologists were definitely human, and humanity had yet to leave Earth. They were digging some ruins in a nondescript place.

Comment: @user14111 I did, it's a very nice one even if it's not the one I'm looking for. Sorry, I thought I had replied to you.